# Related to the partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

let $f$ be a function of two variables, then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$$
but what whould happen if i take this limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$$ Is there any meaning to this limit? for example let $f(x,y)=xy$, So $$\frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}=\frac{(x+h)(y+h)-xy}{h} $$
$$\frac{xy+xh+yh+h^2-xy}{h}=x+y+h$$
Taking the limit as $h\to 0$ we get $$x+y$$
what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$$

is called the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) $\nabla_v f(x,y)$ of $f$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction $v = (1,1)$. If $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $(x,y)$ you just have

$$\nabla_v f(x,y) = f^\prime(x,y)(1,1).$$

Comment: My understanding of the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v=\big<v_1,v_2\big>\neq \vec{0}$ is the limit $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+tv_1,y+tv_2)-f(x,y)}{\|(x+tv_1,y+tv_2)-(x,y)\|}=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+tv_1,y+tv_2)-f(x,y)}{t\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2}}$$ That being said, wouldn't the expression calculated by the OP represent $\frac{(D_vf)(x,y)}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have several flavors of directional derivative definition. See [directional derivative definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Definition)

Comment: I didn't know there was such a variety in the construction of the directional derivative. Thank you.